# Exporting AOSP project into Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-source

I'm trying to use Android Studio to build an enhanced version of Android's default Messaging app, whose AOSP source code can be found at:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Messaging/

How exactly can I convert this AOSP script into a Gradle build? I tried following the instructions they provide in documents like this one:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/tools/idegen/README

using both Linux and Windows, but I never seem to get the IDEGen package. When I try it in Eclipse, as some sources advise, I get a hard-to-resolve complaint about the build path. It's attributed to some annoying bug in the IDE.

Judging by various other questions I saw on Quora and elsewhere, many people have struggled with this issue over the past decade.

Is there any straightforward solution? Can someone, perhaps, recommend a trustworthy tool for converting AOSP into Android builds?

Answer (score 1):

**idegen** is the tool to generate project files (.ipr), so that you can open the whole of AOSP in IntelliJ.  Then you can navigate and edit files for the module you want.

To build only one app, you then use `mmm packages/apps/Messaging` .

That is the **official way**, and how we who work with OS do it.

There is no tool to *export* a single module to Android Studio, because more often than not, these modules depend on other modules too, and very often use non-public APIs ( @hide annotated methods and classes that are not exported in official SDK ).

It's not impossible to do this. It's just that there isn't any automatic import that would do everything for you, and it's going to require a bit of work. 
Some suggestions:

- Import classes and resources manually ( copying src and res folders to an empty Android Studio folder )
- Check Android.mk for dependencies, add what you can via the standard way in gradle. Othewise, you'll have to add them as libs ( .jar/.so ) manually.
- If you have errors about not finding some classes or packages because they aren't part of official SDK, see this It's generally difficult to build them out-of-tree like this. This might be of help for some references https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api.

The first way is straightfoward and easy. The importing way will be trouble, but after having done it, it'll be easier to develop.

Comment: Hiow could I install the mmm command in Linux? Could someone write out the "official" steps or link me to a page you trust that explains them?

Comment: Read this : https://source.android.com/setup/build/building

Comment: I installed a few things, but now when I run the mmm command, I get the following error:

Could not create module-finder: finder encountered 1 errors: [: lstat : no such file or directory]

What could be causing it?

Comment: That has never happened to me. Are you sure you got the repo fully downloaded and are not missing files?

Comment: I initialized the full repo. Was I supposed to sync it in its entirety as opposed to some select projects? I thought the latter was OK because I only need a few (Messaging and whatever supports come with it) and getting every single project requires many gigabytes of disk space.

Comment: Sadly the build system is so interconnected its difficult to just get the part you need. It'd be better to sync it all.

Comment: I can look it up, but does anyone know off-hand how much disk space it requires. I'm on an EC2 server so I wanna request the right amount of space.

Comment: After compilation ( meaning including the out folder ) my repos  take from 100GB to 150GB, depending on vendor specific things. 
Not sure how much for pure AOSP, but take the above as an minimum space limit

Comment: Thanks for the number! Amazon give a measly 8 gigs in the Free Tier by default, but you can pay to get a lot more.